# dynamically create vector<class A> inside constructor of class B, when class A allocates memory when constructed

Tags: c++, constructor, stdvector

I am an embedded developer. And now I am part of a project which uses c++, since our µC didn't support c++ my c++ became a little rusty. I hope some of you can help me.

I want to symulate a SPI-bus-connection with dynamic datalength and number of Slaves.
Since this code tests some µC Code written in plain old C, it's necessary, that the symulation-Interface works with arrays and not with conatainers.

Here are the classes I declared, the description of my problem follows.

```
class LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice;

class LSPI_BusSymulation{ //Interface to the Symulation-Klass
public:
    LSPI_BusSymulation(uint16_t dataSizePerDevice, uint16_t maxNumberOfDevices, uint16_t actualNumberOfDevices);

    // must use normal arrays
    uint16_t* sendSpiData(uint16_t* data, uint16_t dataSize);
private:
    uint16_t actualNumberOfDevices;
    std::vector<LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice> devices;
};

class LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice{//Symulates one bus-device, there can be several
    friend LSPI_BusSymulation;
public:
    LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice(uint16_t dataSizePerDevice, uint16_t maxNumberOfDevices);
    ~LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice();

    // must use normal arrays
    void prepareResponse(uint16_t* data, uint16_t dataSize);
    uint16_t* getBusData();

private:
    // must use normal arrays
    uint16_t* putData(uint16_t* data, uint16_t dataSize);

    uint16_t dataSizePerDevice;
    uint8_t* data;
};
```

The class LSPI_BusSymulation shall create a vector with actualNumberOfDevices * LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice inside it's constructor.
How to implement the constructor of LSPI_BusSymulation properly without generating memory-leaks?
Here is what I have so far. (The other methods aren't important for now)

```
LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice::LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice(uint16_t dataSizePerDevice, uint16_t maxNumberOfDevices)
    : dataSizePerDevice(dataSizePerDevice){
    data = new uint8_t[dataSizePerDevice * (maxNumberOfDevices + 1)];
}

LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice::~LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice(){
    delete data;
}

void LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice::prepareResponse(uint16_t* data, uint16_t dataSize){
    memcpy(this->data, data, dataSize);
}

uint16_t* LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice::getBusData(){
    return (uint16_t*)this->data;
}

uint16_t* LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice::putData(uint16_t* data, uint16_t dataSize){
    memcpy(&this->data[this->dataSizePerDevice], data, dataSize);

    return (uint16_t*)this->data;
}

LSPI_BusSymulation::LSPI_BusSymulation(uint16_t dataSizePerDevice, uint16_t maxNumberOfDevices, uint16_t actualNumberOfDevices)
    : actualNumberOfDevices(actualNumberOfDevices){
    //create a vector with actualNumberOfDevices * LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice
    //Does that work, or will I lose the array inside the created class?
    for(int i = 0; i < actualNumberOfDevices; i++)
        devices.push_back(LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice(dataSizePerDevice, maxNumberOfDevices));
}

uint16_t* LSPI_BusSymulation::sendSpiData(uint16_t* data, uint16_t dataSize){
    uint16_t* retPtr = data;

    for(int i = 0; i < this->actualNumberOfDevices; i++)
        retPtr = devices[i].putData(retPtr, dataSize);

    return retPtr;
}
```

I saw many posts about that problem, but none of these posts had a class with dynamic allocated memory inside it. And I'm not sure if this is a problem.

If I run this simple main:

```
int main(){    
    LSPI_BusSymulation test(10, 10, 10);

   return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:
*** Error in `./a.out': double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000ea0c20 ***

Hope I provided all Information.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: `LSPI_BusSymulation` is trivial to implement as it doesn't create resources (rule of 0). `LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice` is more tricky, as it creates resources, and so should respect rule of 3/5.

Comment: `putData(uint16_t* data, uint16_t dataSize)`. Is that a size in bytes, or a number of elements? Consider `(uint16_t* begin, uint16_t* end)` which makes that unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use C++ use the standard containers this way you will not have to worry about freeing the memory. You can always access to the data allocated by the container if you want to retrieve raw array pointer.

Some sample modification of your code

```
class LSPI_BusSymulation{
...
private:
    // must use normal arrays
    uint16_t* putData(uint16_t* data, uint16_t dataSize);

    uint16_t dataSizePerDevice;
     std::vector<uint8_t> data;
};
```

constructor:

```
LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice::LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice(uint16_t dataSizePerDevice, uint16_t maxNumberOfDevices)
    : dataSizePerDevice(dataSizePerDevice){
    data.resize(dataSizePerDevice * (maxNumberOfDevices + 1));
}
```

Access to the data (sample code)

```
uint16_t* LSPI_BusSymulation_SlaveDevice::getBusData(){
    return (uint16_t*)this->data.data(); // access to the container underlying allocated raw data
}
```

Comment: What about violating [strict aliasing rules](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11)? The cast `(uint16_t*)data.data()` is fine, but dereferencing the resulting pointer is not.

Comment: @muperman I did not investigate your code but I agree with @Evg, it seems strange you cast `unsigned chars` into `unsigned int` in the getBusData() function.

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle I had to do that, because my tests are running on a dekstop-Computer. There I can use uint8_t types. On my Mikrocontroller uint8_t types don't exist. The smallest known type to the hardware ist 16Bit wide.

Comment: @Muperman. We are drifting from your original concern (dynamic allocation in constructor) but if you are simulating the bus you should ensure all the data has the same width (16 bits) otherwise there is a risk that reading uint8_t* by  uint16_t* increments will end up in an out of range access (data) access.